# How to make this vintage glow effect in photoshop?

Tags: photoshop-effects, photography

How can I make this beautiful glow effect on Photoshop and make it look a bit vintage. I'v tried with another layer blurred and with opacity lowered, but the look is different

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track with blurring a layer and reducing its opacity for that fuzzy/dreamy effect. However much of the look will depend on the lighting of the original photograph. A suitable photograph would be one where the subject's face is adequately lit, with a somewhat darker background.

As for the vintage effect, in the Adobe Camera RAW filter you can apply some vintage/aged photo presets.

Examples:

Applying the "Aged Photo" preset in Camera RAW. There are others available too, so feel free to experiment with the other presets.

[image]

Using a blurred layer with reduced opacity, and a Curves adjustment layer to lighten the shadows to give more of that faded look. Obviously, you can tweak the Curves as you wish.

[image]

Since the preset has more or less washed out a lot of the colours, you could also add a Vibrance adjustment layer to bring back some of the colour saturation of the original.

[image]

Image: courtesy of flicker user [Ashraf Saleh](https://www.flickr.com/photos/ash-s/6848169369/), Creative Commons.